# Waf configure error, cannot find pyembed for some reason

Tags: python, c, configuration, waf

I'm trying to configure Planck Likelihood Code using ./waf, but I keep getting the following error after calling `./waf configure CC=gcc python=/opt/local/bin/python cfitsio_lib=/opt/local/lib cfitsio_include=/opt/local/include --lapack_mkl=${MKLROOT} --install_all_deps`:

```
Testing pyembed configuration: Could not build a python embedded interpreter
No suitable python distribution found 
Cause: 'The configuration failed'
```

I have no idea how to proceed from here... Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the relevant part from the `config.log` file for the configuration attempt also. I'm using Python 2.7 on Mac OS, and it seems to be installed fine (as far as I can tell).

```
python-config
/opt/local/bin/python2.7-config
find program=['/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python-config', 'python2.7-config', 'python-config-2.7', 'python2.7m-config'] paths=['/Users/USER/Desktop/montepython_public-3.3/montepython/', '/opt/local/bin', '/opt/local/sbin', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/bin', '/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/sbin', '/Library/TeX/texbin', '/Library/Apple/usr/bin'] var='PYTHON_CONFIG' -> ['/opt/local/bin/python2.7-config']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Asking python-config for pyembed '--cflags --libs --ldflags --embed' flags
['/opt/local/bin/python2.7-config', '--cflags', '--libs', '--ldflags', '--embed']
err: Usage: /opt/local/bin/python2.7-config [--prefix|--exec-prefix|--includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags|--help]

not found
from /Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01: The configuration failed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Asking python-config for pyembed '--cflags --libs --ldflags' flags
['/opt/local/bin/python2.7-config', '--cflags', '--libs', '--ldflags']
out: -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -pipe -Os -isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
-lpython2.7 -lintl -ldl -framework CoreFoundation
-L/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lintl -ldl -framework CoreFoundation

Unhandled flag '-pipe'
Unhandled flag '-Wall'
Unhandled flag '-Wstrict-prototypes'
yes
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing pyembed configuration
==>

#include <Python.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void Py_Initialize(void);
    void Py_Finalize(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   (void)argc; (void)argv;
   Py_Initialize();
   Py_Finalize();
   return 0;
}

<==
[1/2] Compiling [32mbuild/.conf_check_e02afcfd7f3c9a900cd99ee408c985e3/test.c[0m

['gcc', '-fno-strict-aliasing', '-fno-common', '-dynamic', '-Os', '-isysroot/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk', '-DNDEBUG', '-g', '-fwrapv', '-O3', '-I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7', '-DPYTHONDIR="/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python2.7/site-packages"', '-DPYTHONARCHDIR="/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/lib/python2.7/site-packages"', '../test.c', '-c', '-o/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/.conf_check_e02afcfd7f3c9a900cd99ee408c985e3/testbuild/test.c.1.o']
[2/2] Linking [33mbuild/.conf_check_e02afcfd7f3c9a900cd99ee408c985e3/testbuild/testprog[0m

['gcc', '-arch', 'x86_64', 'test.c.1.o', '-o/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/build/.conf_check_e02afcfd7f3c9a900cd99ee408c985e3/testbuild/testprog', '-L/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib', '-L/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config', '-lm', '-ldl', '-lutil', '-lpthread', '-lpython2.7', '-lintl', '-ldl', '-lpython2.7', '-lintl', '-ldl']
err: ld: library not found for -lintl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

from /Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01: Test does not build: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/.waf-2.0.17-c5414c9b1eca70e1add79159e16494fe/waflib/Configure.py", line 325, in run_build
    bld.compile()
  File "/Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01/.waf-2.0.17-c5414c9b1eca70e1add79159e16494fe/waflib/Build.py", line 176, in compile
    raise Errors.BuildError(self.producer.error)
BuildError: Build failed
 -> task in 'testprog' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)

Could not build a python embedded interpreter
from /Users/USER/Desktop/code/plc_3.0/plc-3.01: The configuration failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker did not find libintl.
Are you sure It is installed On your system? If yes the library must be installed in a standard library directory otherwise you must use -L"lib_path"

Comment: Where can you see this? I can't see any mention of the libintl library.

Comment: err: ld: library not found for -lintl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status